# Jest mock the result of function but not calculating the number of calls

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have the following code:

```js
const results: MessagingDeviceResult[] = [{ messageId: "some unique value"}]
const response = { results } as MessagingDevicesResponse
const returnValue = Promise.resolve<MessagingDevicesResponse>(response)
const spy = jest.spyOn(admin.messaging(), 'sendToDevice').mockReturnValue(returnValue)

pushNotification({
  from,
  to,
  body,
})

expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
```

On the console I can check that mocked function was called because I added a `console.log` on the code

```js
const { results } = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload)

console.log('results', results)
```

Which results:

```sh
console.log
  results [ { messageId: 'some unique value' } ]
```

But, when I call `toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)` to check if the function was called, Jest tells me that was not called!

```sh
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

Expected number of calls: 1
Received number of calls: 0
```

What is the common cases that can cause this? The function was mocked successfully but not registering the number of calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out, pushNotification is a `async` function and I forget the `await` on call

```
await pushNotification({
  from,
  to,
  body,
})
```